# Running a script on select tabs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

I am not a coder, but I can normally do enough trial and error to get my script to function in the way I want my google sheet to work.

**The goal of my script:**
I want cell A to time stamp anytime that cell B is edited. It is doing exactly what I want on my first tab. I need it to run only on the first 5 tabs etc, but then exclude the following tabs that I want running my Queries for other information from the first tabs.

-I have gotten the code to run on all tabs. I have tried editing the SHEETNAME = to include the sheets I want the script ran on. I have changed a ton of it, but I decided to just paste the script that runs how I desired on the singular tab.

-I may need to tear the script apart and restart, but it is tough when it is achieving the perfect result on the first tab labeled 'Client'.

*Current script that is only working on a singular tab*

```
1 /**
 
2 * Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.

3 */

4  

5 //CORE VARIABLES

6 // The column you want to check if something is entered.

7 var COLUMNTOCHECK = 2;

8 // Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]

9 var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,-1];

10 // Sheet you are working on

11 var SHEETNAME = 'Client'

12  

13 function onEdit(e) {
  
14 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
15 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 
16 //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  
17 if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
   
18 var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
   
19  //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.

20    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) {

21      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);

22      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());

23      }

24  }

25 }
```

Link to the test document
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hOobE5vDzMu6jjuXQcTRMRMIMv6TWDWHeipDnyrmzSM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Have you read [Run script through multiple Google sheet tabs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149989/196152) or [How to run script on multiple Google Sheet tabs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115076/196152) or [Run Google Sheets script on multiple sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/141733/196152) or [Apply simple script to specific tabs in a Google Sheet (I know zero code)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/162220/196152) or [running script over multiple sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158348/196152)

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz ! I did look at this thread earlier and I am editing my script to see if I can make it work! I am still having trouble getting it to work on only selected tabs, but I may have it figured out. Once I do I will post the corrected script!

Comment: Thank you again @Tedinoz!!! I got it running.